# Pass piped command line to xargs

Tags: awk, command-line, pipe, xargs

I have this command line:

```
curl https://token-api/42 | awk '{ print $0 }'
```

which produces this output:

```
{"id":"PX-12345","expiresAtUtc":"2020-07-05T06:55:52","createdUtc":"2019-07-15T06:55:52"}
```

The `awk '{ print $0 }'` is there to ensure there is a newline appended at the end of the output.

Now I want to do the same but for a csv list of user ids (`users.csv`) instead of a hard-coded `42` by using `xargs`. So I tried this and a number of variations:

```
awk -F, '{print "curl https://token-api/$0 | awk \'''\''{ print $0 }\'''\''"}' < users.csv | xargs -P1 -I {} sh -c '{}'
```

This produces the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\'' treated as plain `''
awk: cmd. line:1: {
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

If I remove the `xargs` part, I get the following output:

```
curl https://token-api/$0 | awk '{ print $0 }'
```

which is passed to `xargs`. I guess my problem is with the `$0` that is used twice but I have no idea to escape this.

If there is another (better) way to append a newline to the output of curl, that might help too because without that it's working fine. However, then I get a long list of unseparated JSON documents as output like this:

```
{"id":"PX-12345","expiresAtUtc":"...","createdUtc":"..."}{"id":"PX-12346","expiresAtUtc":"...","createdUtc":"..."}{"id":"PX-12347","expiresAtUtc":"...","createdUtc":"..."}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly? just append a line to the output of `curl`? `{ curl http://foo.com/bar; echo; }`.

Comment: What does your `users.csv` look like?

Comment: @mosvy the 'trick' with `echo` works, I was making it too complex I guess. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than executing a command for every line of the csv file, it might be easier to take advantage of curls multiple URL feature.

> You can specify multiple URLs or parts of URLs by writing part sets within braces as in: http://site.{one,two,three}.com

I'm not sure what your csv file looks like, seems like it's all in a single line? If so you could just `cat` the file and combine with the curl command.

`curl "https://token-api/{$(cat users.csv)}"`

Still needs a bit of cleaning up.

`curl "https://token-api/{$(cat users.csv)}" 2>/dev/null | sed '1d;s/--_curl_--.*$//'; echo`

The `sed` command deletes the first line since that will just be the first URL, then removes the rest of the URLs, which leaves a useful newline between entries. Finally just `echo` to end with a newline.

Comment: As usual, I made my example code too simple. The request is actually a POST request where the data posted comes from the csv file. So I can't use curls multiple URL feature unfortunately.

Comment: That makes more sense, I think if it's getting that complex it might be better making a shell script rather than trying to get it all into a single command. Maybe something like `while IFS=, read -r USERID DATA1 _ DATA2 _; do; curl "https://token-api/$USERID" -d "data1=$DATA1&data2=$DATA2"; echo; done < users.csv`